# How to find all files,with substring, e.g. xyz (caseinsensitive) in filename within particular type (*.txt) using linux command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, find, locate

I have some bunch of files, which has "xyz" in the filename, This "xyz" can be case insensitive, e.g. "XYz" or "xYz". Wish to display all possible combination of the files in from current working node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `find . -type f -iname "*xyz*"`.

`find` is a standard unix utility that will search for items in a directory tree starting from the path of the first argument, and print them to the terminal by default. In this case, `find .` means search starting at the current working directory. (`.` is unix shorthand for the current working directory.) the `-type f` argument means look only for files. `-iname "*xyz*"` means look for anything with "xyz" anywhere in the item's path, ignoring case.